# How to get data from api routes in next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, middleware

Hi i am having api routes which listens to incoming request ,

Code looks something like this

```
async function handler(req, res) {
// Run the middleware
await runMiddleware(req, res, cors)

// Rest of the API logic
res.json({ message: 'Hello Everyone!' })
console.log(req.body)
}

export default handler
```

whenever this request comes in , how can i interact with this data and use these on pages?

Answer (score 1):

If you need this data before the page is rendered then you would not use API routes. You can (and should) use all kinds of things directly inside `getServerSideProps` OR `getStaticProps`. This basically means that you could query your DB directly inside this functions. No need to go to the "server" to do that. It's a big context switch. Speaking of context, you can get url information and all sorts of things as argument to those functions mentioned above.

If you need this data after the page is rendered then you should use client-side fetch calls to get data. You can read up on that, it's basic react data fetching.

**Relevant links**

Context: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#context-parameter (for accessing stuff like params, query) before the page loads

React data fetching: https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data/

Comment: the problem is i dont want to use get request , there would be authentication taking place in third party website and that website would give a post request to frontend and i have to store that token in session and redirect user...

Comment: If 3rd party website is one of the known vendors, I would suggest using NextAuth package. Basically what you do is wrap your _app file with a Provider component and then extract session data either on server side or client side.

https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/example#configure-shared-session-state
You can then choose what do you want to protect. E.g.

`export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const session: { user: UserSession } = await getSession(context)
  if (!session || !session.user) {
    return { props: {} } // or redirect
  }`

Comment: Formatting is a bit bad, hope it's still helpful. Basically look up NextAuth and use it if possible. It's an awesome resource. Or create a custom solution, but you would probably come up with something similar to next-auth.

Comment: we can't use next auth , basically after authentication we are using query string to get the token .. can we replace the query string method to anything?

Comment: Not really clear, gonna have to ask you to write in more detail. What service are you using, in which way, and what is exactly the issue.